# Conditional compilation in Agda

Tags: conditional-compilation, agda

How can I write Agda code against multiple versions of the standard library?

For instance `Data.Maybe.IsJust` got renamed to `Data.Maybe.Is-just`. Similarly `Data.Fin.Props` is moving to `Data.Fin.Properties`. Unfortunately little work has been invested to retain backwards compatibility, so even targeting to adjacent releases has become difficult. Conventional options like running `cpp` as a preprocessor are inconvenient, because they break the emacs `agda2-mode`.

Comment: I think that is a missing feature. I suggest create a new request on http://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/list.